# Trying to come up with features to extract from sound waves to use for an AI song composer

Tags: audio, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, signal-processing

I am planning on making an AI song composer that would take in a bunch of songs of one instrument, extract musical notes (like ABCDEFG) and certain features from the sound wave, preform machine learning (most likely through recurrent neural networks), and output a sequence of ABCDEFG notes (aka generate its own songs / music).

I think that this would be an unsupervised learning problem, but I am not really sure.

I figured that I would use recurrent neural networks, but I have a few questions on how to approach this:
- What features from the sound wave I should extract so that the output music is melodious?

Also, I have a few other questions as well
- Is it possible, with recurrent neural networks, to output a vector of sequenced musical notes (ABCDEF)?
- Any smart way I can feed in the features of the soundwaves as well as sequence of musical notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i did something similar once(making a shazam like app on matlab) , i think you can use FFT(Fast Fourier Transform ) to break it down into the constituent frequencies and their corresponding amplitudes .Then you can use the frequency range of different instruments  to select them out of the whole bunch and classify .

Comment: You will need additional transformations to get robust data from the FFT like the MFCC. The FFT alone is too noisy as a base for training data.

Answer (score 1):

I already tried something similar with an RNN (Recurrent Neural Network). Try using an LSTM network (Long Short Term Memory), they are a WAY better than RNNs for this type of data processing from what I read afterward, because they do not suffer from the "vanishing gradient problem".

What `Chris Thaliyath` said is a good hint on how to train the feature detector.